# condition in applescript if directory is empty do this, else do that

Tags: applescript

So far I've got this:

```
property watch_folder : alias "Macintosh HD:Users:davidcuster:iFlicks:Watch Folder:"

tell application "Finder"
    count files of entire contents of watch_folder
    if the result = 0 then
        quit
    end if
end tell
```

I'm looking for an easier way to do this.

Comment: Can you tell us why it must be an Applescript for some simple work also an Automator Action is enough. If it is more complex maybe a shell script will serve you better than an Applescript. Sometimes also a Combination is best.  So to help you finding the easiest way to do something you should tell us what you will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is any easier, but it's faster than getting the entire contents if the folder contains many files in subfolders:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if items of (POSIX file "/Users/username/folder" as alias) is {} then
        --
    else
        --
    end if
end tell
```

You can also replace `Finder` with `System Events`. For some reason Finder doesn't include hidden files but System Events does.